# Returning value from one column or, if not found, search it in another

Tags: excel, function

I have a column with phone numbers and another one in which I use LOOKUPV to look up the same phone numbers in another file (I use this file to look up some missing numbers, but I don`t have all of them). In a third column, I want to use a function to treat these phone numbers (they need to be formatted in a certain way), but my problem is that in some cases I have lines in which the phone number in column A is present and the number in column B is not, or vice versa. I want to use a function which looks up a number in both columns and returns only one phone number. How can this be done? Example:

| Phones 1 | Phones 2 | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 |  | 12345678 |
|  | 55577788 | 55577788 |
| 88899900 | 88899900 | 88899900 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the data starts in cell A2, put this in cell C2:

```
=if(and(A2="",B2=""),"error",if(A2="",B2,A2))
```

If you have the ID in col A and the phone numbers in B and C, then something like:

```
=iferror(vlookup(D2,A2:C10,2,0),vlookup(D2,A2:C10,3,0)
```

This assumes that both B2 and C2 will not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if function` to check which column is not empty and return it's value.

```
=if(A2="",B2,A2)
```

Or

```
=if(LEN(A2)=0,B2,A2)
```